# Directories not being copied on databricks notebook

Tags: python, databricks

Considering this piece of code of mine:

```
# Define the base directory on DBFS and local directories
dbfs_base_dir = 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/cnh_dataset/'
local_base_dir = '/tmp/cnh_dataset/'

# Create the local directories if they don't exist
os.makedirs(local_base_dir + 'train', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(local_base_dir + 'val', exist_ok=True)

# Copy data from DBFS to local directories
dbutils.fs.cp(dbfs_base_dir + 'train/', local_base_dir + 'train/', recurse=True) # Updated paths
dbutils.fs.cp(dbfs_base_dir + 'val/', local_base_dir + 'val/', recurse=True) # Updated paths

# Print the contents of the local directory after the copy operation
print("Contents of /tmp/cnh_dataset/train:", os.listdir('/tmp/cnh_dataset/train'))

# Check that the expected folder structure is present
print("Files in /tmp/cnh_dataset/train:", os.listdir(local_base_dir + 'train'))
print("Files in /tmp/cnh_dataset/val:", os.listdir(local_base_dir + 'val'))
```

All files from the dbfs file should be copied to the underlying OS of the notebook, and I know the path is correct because I've checked using the databricks CLI. But I still get this error:

```
Contents of /tmp/cnh_dataset/train: []
Files in /tmp/cnh_dataset/train: []
Files in /tmp/cnh_dataset/val: []
FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find any class folder in /tmp/cnh_dataset/train.
```

Nothing is being copied, am I using `dbutils.fs.cp` wrong? I've read the documentation, it seems ok:

https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbutils.fs.cp` does not support copying files from/to local filesystem. If filesystem is not explicitly specified in source/destination paths, it assumes it's DBFS by default, so your:

```
dbutils.fs.cp(<...>, '/tmp/cnh_dataset/train/', recurse=True)
```

In reality is:

```
dbutils.fs.cp(<...>, 'dbfs:/tmp/cnh_dataset/train/', recurse=True)
```

While documentation mentions that copying between filesystems is possible, it rather refers to things like Azure Datalake Storage (`adl:/<xxx>`) - that could be the source of confusion.

Since DBFS is mounted in all nodes under `/dbfs` local directory, you can simply copy data using a shell command:

```
cp -r /dbfs/FileStore/tables/cnh_dataset/{train,val} /tmp/cnh_dataset/
```

Or use something like `shutil.copytree` if you want to keep it in Python.